# R function with variable number of ifelse breaks

Tags: r, function

I would like to create a function to solve the following problem.
I have a data frame. Some of the columns are numeric and for some of those columns, I would like to create a new column of factors using ifelse(). A minimal example is below. The actual data frame has over 200 columns.
Note that the number of breaks is different for each column.
I can write an ifelse statement and go column-by-column. I need a function.
I am hoping for a two-step solution. The first will handle a column at a time. The second will do the entire project in one shot. I have faced this situation before, so I hope the solver can provide adequate insight so that I can do future problems on my own.
I am hoping for a base R solution or possibly a tidyverse solution.
The first function call might be something like:

```
makeFactors(df1 = weightsDF, oldCol = size1, newCol = size3, breaks = c(100, 150, 200, 300), values = c(“small”, “medium”, “large”, “error”))
```

```
weightsDF = data.frame(size1 = c(450, 270, 30, 180, 120), size2 = c(45, 170, 300, 80, 120), 
                       people = c('Al', 'Al', 'Barb', 'Barb', 'Carol'))
weightsDF$size3 = with(weightsDF, factor(ifelse(size1 >= 100 & size1 <= 150, "small",
                                         ifelse(size1 > 150 & size1 <= 200, "medium",
                                                ifelse(size1 > 200 & size1 <= 300, "large", "error")))))
weightsDF$size4 = with(weightsDF, factor(ifelse(size2 >= 100 & size2 <= 140, "tiny",
                                         ifelse(size2 > 140 & size2 <= 200, "big","error"))))
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a preliminary solution that you might have to modify in order to reflect the exact data you have.

```
makeFactor <- function(df, oldCol, newCol, brea, names){ 
            new <- as.vector(cut(
                                        as.numeric(as.matrix(df[oldCol])), 
                                        breaks = c(brea, 100000), 
                                        right = TRUE, 
                                        labels = names)
                                           )
            dfnew <- cbind(df, new) 
            names(dfnew)[names(dfnew) == "new"] <- newCol
            return(dfnew)
}
```

A test run with

```
makeFactor(weightsDF, oldCol = "size1", 
           newCol = "Test", 
           brea = c(0, 100, 150, 200, 300), 
           names = c("small", "medium", "big", "large",               
                     "very large"))
```

gives the result

```
   size1 size2 people       Test
1   450    45     Al very large
2   270   170     Al      large
3    30   300   Barb      small
4   180    80   Barb        big
5   120   120  Carol     medium
```

The basic idea is to use the Base R function `cut()` to find the appropriate values.

Is that what you had in mind?

Comment: Thanks. Your solution solves this problem. I tried the code on the real data.
Would you be able to show me how to use it on multiple columns (other than just repeating the process)? The idea is to set up some objects and then process them.  
The great thing about cut() is that it has parameters that help solve the problem. For future reference, is there a way to solve the problem using ifelse()?

Comment: You mean you want to use the function simultaneously on multiple columns instead of sequentially column by column? I think your solution with ´ifelse()` is already sufficient, and there's not a lot more to do.